# Is it possible to use the package name in a local package import?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I'm building a package and I wanted to build tests only if a certain function of the same local package is called. I don't want to get too much into the details but I am traversing the code with a Babel plugin to look for a specific module import to perform some actions.

The problem is that when I import this function I use locale paths, like this:

```
import { myFunction } from './';
```

I would like instead to have something like:

```
import { myFunction } from 'my-real-package-name';
```

I tried to install my package locally but now I am getting this error when trying to build:

```bash
error TS5055: Cannot write file '/my-real-package-name/lib/index.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.
```

I could always check if the import is from `./` or `my-real-package-name` but I would prefer to just use `my-real-package-name` since it's safer to avoid unexpected issue.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Still not sure what you want to achieve, but most of bundlers support package aliases (usualy something like `alias: {'my-real-package-name' : './my-real-package-name/lib/index.d.ts'}`)

Comment: I actually don't use any bundler in this package. I was wondering if there was another way to create aliases like that natively in package.json or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link) or [`yarn link`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/link/) depending on your package manager.

From npm documentation page:

> This is handy for installing your own stuff, so that you can work on it and test
> iteratively without having to continually rebuild.
>
> Package linking is a two-step process.
>
> First, npm link in a package folder with no arguments will create a
> symlink in the global folder {prefix}/lib/node_modules/ that
> links to the package where the npm link command was executed. It will
> also link any bins in the package to {prefix}/bin/{name}. Note that
> npm link uses the global prefix (see npm prefix -g for its value).
>
> Next, in some other location, npm link package-name will create a
> symbolic link from globally-installed package-name to node_modules/ of
> the current folder.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> cd ~/projects/node-redis    # go into the package directory
> npm link                    # creates global link
> cd ~/projects/node-bloggy   # go into some other package directory.
> npm link redis
> ```

Comment: This has the same effect as trying to install the same package locally. It generates this error when building: `error TS5055: Cannot write file '/my-real-package-name/lib/index.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.`

Comment: The error (TS5055) means that the file has been used on the compilation process and its being overriden. Try setting the "outdir" property on tsconfig or running typescript with the explain flag to make it more verbose

Comment: --explainFiles doesn't provide more info - same error